# Java heap size memory at map step on hive sql

Tags: java, memory, hive

I run the following hql:

```
select new.uid as uid, new.category_id as category_id, new.atag as atag,
new.rank_idx + CASE when old.rank_idx is not NULL then old.rank_idx else 0 END as rank_idx 
from (
        select a1.uid, a1.category_id, a1.atag, row_number() over(distribute by a1.uid, a1.category_id sort by a1.cmt_time) as rank_idx from (
            select app.uid, 
            CONCAT(cast(app.knowledge_point_id_list[0] as string),'#',cast(app.type_id as string))  as category_id, 
            app.atag as atag, app.cmt_time as cmt_time 
            from model.mdl_psr_app_behavior_question_result app 
            where app.subject = 'english' 
            and app.dt = '2016-01-14'
            and app.cmt_timelen > 1000
            and app.cmt_timelen < 120000
        ) a1 
    ) new
left join (
    select uid, category_id, rank_idx from model.mdl_psr_mlc_app_count_last
    where subject = 'english'
    and dt = '2016-01-13'
    ) old
on new.uid = old.uid
and new.category_id = old.category_id
```

Originally mdl_psr_mlc_app_count_last and mdl_psr_mlc_app_count_day are stored as JsonSerde, the query runs.

My colleague suggests that JsonSerde is highly inefficient and occupies too much space. PARQUET is a better choice for me.

When I did, the query broke with the following error log:

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper: ExecMapper: processing 1 rows: used memory = 1024506232
>   2016-01-19 16:36:56,119 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper: ExecMapper: processing 10 rows: used memory = 1024506232
>   2016-01-19 16:36:56,130 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper: ExecMapper: processing 100 rows: used memory = 1024506232
>   2016-01-19 16:36:56,248 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper: ExecMapper: processing 1000 rows: used memory = 1035075896
>   2016-01-19 16:36:56,694 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper: ExecMapper: processing 10000 rows: used memory = 1045645560
>   2016-01-19 16:36:57,056 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper: ExecMapper: processing 100000 rows: used memory = 1065353232

It looks like java memory problem. Somebody suggests me to try:

```
SET mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx900m;
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=8048;
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts='-Xmx8048M';
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb=1024; 
set mapreduce.map.java.opts='-Xmx4096M';
set mapred.child.map.java.opts='-Xmx4096M';
```

It still breaks, with the same error message. Now someone else suggests:

```
SET mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx900m;
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=1024;
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts='-Xmx1024M';
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb=1024; 
set mapreduce.map.java.opts='-Xmx1024M';
set mapreduce.child.map.java.opts='-Xmx1024M';
set mapred.reduce.tasks = 40;
```

Now it runs without a glitch.

Can someone explain me why?

================================
btw: although it runs, the reduce step is very slow. While you are at it, could you explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, YARN has a poor support for parquet format.

Quote [Mapr](https://www.mapr.com/blog/best-practices-yarn-resource-management)

> For example, if the MapReduce job sorts parquet files, Mapper needs to cache the whole Parquet row group in memory. I have done tests to prove that the larger the row group size of parquet files is, the larger Mapper memory is needed. In this case, make sure the Mapper memory is large enough without triggering OOM.

I am not exactly sure why different setting in the question matters, but the simple solution is to drop parquet and use orc. A bit performance loss in exchange of bug free.